# If cell a = value in column b copy and save the value of cell c

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need some help here if someone can provide me a code for this.

Scenario:
cell A is a drop down list

column B has a static value

cell C is where they input the value

cell D is where the value of cell c stored

so if cell A = value in column B, the value of cell C should be copied and saved to cell D, because cell A is a dropdown list, if I change the cell A to another value, cell c should reset to "blank", but the value of cell D should remain to where cell A = cell B.

I have this code inputed in cell D, but when I change the value of cell A, the value of cell D also disappear which it should remain where cell a = cell b

=vlookup(A2,Sheet1!B2:C5,2,FALSE)

I'm new to excel vba so any help will be much appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Overly simplified, but here's a solution ...

First, here is a screenshot of how I set up the data ...

[image]

The data in column A uses a drop down list. Values that may or may not be the same are entered into column B. Column C are user entries and Column D gets those upon recalculation.

Here is the code behind the Recalculate button ...

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Public Sub Recalculate()
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    For iLoop = 2 To 4
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iLoop, 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iLoop, 2) Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iLoop, 4) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iLoop, 3)
        Else
             Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iLoop, 3) = ""
        End If
    Next iLoop
End Sub
```

I didn't do anything to handle adding rows, etc. Just blindly calculating as you requested.

I changed the value in A3 and here is a screen shot of the result.

[image]

Comment: but it seems that its only limited to cell A2 should be equal only to cell B2, what if cell A2 is equal to cell B3 not on B2? 

its like on vlookup function i guess where cell A2 searches for where it equals its value on column B.

Comment: Well, I (and probably the answerer as well) interpreted your question as comparing all cells in A with all cells in B. If you want to compare A2 against all cells in B, that's a different question entirely and you should update your question to reflect that this is in fact what you are trying to accomplish.